MySQL execute many not executing from list
I have some code that works to manage subscriptions of stock market tickers for a websocket.  At the end of the websocket run I have a function to clear all subscriptions for a clean slate the next time it runs.  I have been able to do this using a loop function but can not get an executemany to run the whole query without a loop. I have issues getting the executemany to work at all in the rest of my program so any help with that in general will help.
Current attempt:
edit: removed block of code no longer being used for testing. See below under test code for current attempt
MySQL class for data connections
For reference I have a class for my db connection which I will put below to make sure I do not have an issue there either.
# MySQL class for db connection:

edit: updated dbwrite() and dbread() per comments from Barmar

class mysqlconnclass:
    def __init__(self,hostname,username,password,db):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.db = db
        self.connection = self.dbConnection()
        self.c = self.connection.cursor(dictionary=True)


    def dbConnection(self):
        connection = None
        try:
            connection = cpy.connect(
                host = self.hostname,
                user = self.username,
                passwd = self.password,
                database = self.db,
            )

            print(connection)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        return connection
    
    def dbwrite(self,query,data=[]):
        execute = 0
        if len(data) == 0:
            self.c.execute(query)
        if isinstance(data,dict):
            self.c.execute(query,data)
        if isinstance(data,list) & len(data) > 0:
            self.c.executemany(query,data)
            execute = 1

        self.connection.commit()


    def dbread(self,query,data=[]):
        execute = 0
        if len(data) == 0:
            self.c.execute(query)
        elif isinstance(data,dict):
            self.c.execute(query,data)
        elif isinstance(data,list) & len(data) > 0:
            self.c.executemany(query,data)
            execute = 1

        # return cursor result if it did not executemany as execute many does not return values.
        
        if execute == 0: return self.c.fetchall()

Current testing
Tried below in a jupyter notebook for testing with no avail
I noticed most online tutorials the data inserted for an execute many was a tuple so I tried below with no change in the result.
edit: added a print function to check my output just after the dbwrite()
cursubsSelect = "SELECT * from tickers WHERE current_sub = '1'"

currsubs = dbconn.dbread(cursubsSelect)
remsubs = []
for item in currsubs:
    remsubs.append((item['id'],))
query = 'UPDATE tickers SET current_sub = False WHERE id = %s'

dbconn.dbwrite(query,remsubs)
print(query)
print(remsubs)

output:
UPDATE tickers SET current_sub = False WHERE id = %s
[('01J6XP1N4481D2NME8TAP7BBYG',), ('01J6XP1N643NT69SJZ064CFYRV',), ('01J6XP1N7S5S415QHHC0ETSECW',), ... ('01J6XP1PXBSW7QGN5NNRR4NVK4',), ('01J6XP1PYZAVHZCRNR9ND6TNJR',)]```


tuple(item['id']) is not how you wrap a value in a tuple; if item['id'] is a string, it will split it into a tuple of characters, e.g. tuple('foo') => ('f', 'o', 'o'). It should be (item['id'],)

BTW, dbread() will execute the query twice if data is an empty dict. You should use elif for conditions that are supposed to be mutually exclusive.

dbwrite() and dbread() will not execute the query at all if data is a list and len(data) == 1.

len(data) > 1 should be len(data) > 0. But you don't even need that condition if you use elif, because you already checked for 0 earlier.

Noted on the dbread() and dbwrite().  I have not had the issue on a single item in a list as intentionaly most of my code uses dictionaries instead of list for most DB read / writes.

I did attempt with the tuple using (item['id],) as noted in my last attempts with a Jupyter notebook I use for testing pieces.

What is the value of len(remsubs)?

BTW, don't use SELECT * if you only need the id, use SELECT id. Then you could simply use remsubs = dbconn.dbread(cursubsSelect)

Why are you using two queries in the first place? Why not just UPDATE tickers SET current_sub = False WHERE current_sub = '1'?

@Barmar I did not think of using a single query for the issue as your last comment shows. That does solve this specific issue I was having but does not answer for me why the executemany is not working.  The reason is I am still relatively new to *SQL and as a result usually sloppy with my implementations at first until I learn a better way.

Other than the points I mentioned above, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. So I suspect that the SELECT query is only returning 1 row, so none of the if conditions work.

len(remsubs) is 33 right now.

Why do you set execute = 1 when len(data) > 0? Why don't you want to return the results?

dbwrite() never uses the execute variable, why do you assign it?

They used to be the same function.  Forgot to remove execute from dbwrite() when I separated them.

I just realized that your whole logic about when to use executemany() is wrong. What if you have a query with two placeholders? You'll pass a list of two values, it should just use execute(), but it will mistakenly use executemany()

Maybe you shouldn't be writing your own abstraction layer like this. Use an existing ORM library like SQLAlchemy.

I typically use a dictionary for passing multiple placeholders. see below for another section I use for writing to my log table.
 logdata = {'id':ulid.new().str,'task':self.logtask,'msg':msg}
self.db.dbwrite(self.logquery,logdata)```

where my logquery is:
```self.logquery = 'INSERT INTO logs (id,task,logmsg) VALUES (%(id)s,%(task)s,%(msg)s)'```

I suggest you run the code under a debugger, or add print statements, to see which if branch it's taking.
